# How to solve "config.h file not found"? when running app from the react native on the device?

Tags: android, ios, github, react-native, react-native-ios

Getting error "Config.h file not found, lexical or preprocessor error."

I am running app in the device from the xcode project.

I have google and found many solutions but haven't worked, I tried this

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14382

And when I try to run in the iOS simulator getting this error

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10401

Tried to follow the above url but didn't work.

Please let me know how to solve the issue.
Thanks

Comment: Please remove the android tag, I almost ignored this in the google search results since it had an `android -` prefix.

Answer (score 15):

**try it**

```
Open Terminal, go to your project’s root folder and do:
cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4/
```

[image]
    Run the configure script:
    ./configure
[image]
    Open Xcode and try to run your app.

**Xcode 10**

```
"react-native": "0.57.5"

cd ./node_modules/react-native && scripts/ios-install-third-party.sh && cd third-party && cd $(ls | grep 'glog' | awk '{print $1}') && ./configure
```

Comment: I've faced this new error : No member named '__rip' in '__darwin_arm_thread_state64' at signalhandler.cc

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue and it's fixed by these commands:-

yarn

```
rm -rf node_modules/
yarn cache clean
yarn install
```

npm

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm cache clean  
npm i
```

Comment: This fixed my problem.  However, I had to use `yarn cache clean`.  I may be using a different version of yarn though.

Comment: Be cautious with yarn clean: ```Note: This command is considered for advanced use cases only. Unless you are experiencing
issues with the amount of files that are installed as part of node_modules it is not
recommended to use this command. It uses a heuristic to identify files that may not be
needed from a distributed package and may not be entirely safe.``` https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/2206

Answer (score 3):

For me:

```
# rm -rf  node_modules

# npm cache verify  (Because I'm using npm version 5.0.3)

# npm install

Xcode Clean

Xcode Run
```

If that doesn't work,

In the Terminal, navigate to the `react-native/third-party/glog folder` inside `node_modules`

(for me, this was `cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4`)

Once actively in this folder,

```
#run ../../scripts/ios-configure-glog.sh
```

Glog is configured and the required `config.h` header file is created for `Xcode` to find

Answer (score 0):

Just go on the config.h file, click on the right panel and add the file to the app target by checking the right case. Clean and compile again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the third-party folder in your node_modules/react-native folder.